# MySQL authentication, how to pad the 20-byte salt

Tags: authentication, cryptography, mysql, sha

Im authenticating with a mysql server with the authentication method listed [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/secure-password-authentication.html#packet-Authentication%3a%3aNative41).

I observed the salt and hash using wireshark, and I know the password, but I am having trouble reproducing the hash I saw.

My question is about the salt. I observed in wireshark that this salt was only 12 bytes and null terminated. I noticed someone [else had a salt of the same length as mine](https://www.portcullis-security.com/cracking-mysql-network-authentication-hashes-with-john-the-ripper/). So...is this salt padded? How is it padded? I can't find anything about how to turn the 12bytes they give me into the 20bytes I use in my calculations.

Answer (score 1):

The blog post at Portcullis security seems to be saying that you have to hash the 12-byte "salt" with SHA1 to turn it into a 20-byte string before prepending it to the hashed password.

Comment: Hm . It's odd because my code to regenerate the has still doesn't work `sha1(pw) ^ sha1( sha1(salt).sha1(sha1(pw)))` should be correct.